# Npm configure axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, axios

How I can set baseUrl for axios using npm param?

I would like to write command like this `npm run build --baseUrl={url address}` and in axios config set baseURL param to param from command.

It is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible if you call that `--baseUrl` like that, as if you do it like that, you're going to have to define `--baseUrl` for `npm start` and other scripts, and you'll quickly end up with a spaghetti code.

I humbly suggest a way to mitigate this issue:

- Create an `.env` file that is filled with your environment variables for development. Add this to `.gitignore` and don't push this into your production server. This file is not used for production.
- Add a new `BASE_URL` variable, like:

```
BASE_URL=http://YOUR_API_LOCATION/
```

- Use libraries like `dotenv` (install by `npm i dotenv`) so you can read `.env` files.
- Create a new utility for axios, let's say:

```js
// client.js
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// get all environment variables here.
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });

// create a new axios instance with the base url from your '.env' file.
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  /* other custom settings */
});

module.exports = axiosInstance;
```

You can reuse your `axiosInstance` like this:

```js
// request.js
const axiosCustomClient = require('./client');

axiosCustomClient.get('relative/path/to/your/api');
```